# SQL Systematically update cells in adjacent columns

Tags: sql-server

[Table Structures Illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iChCr.png)

My main problem is how to traverse a specified number of columns, and make the proper checks of: beginning with a given starting column have I reached the stop value (the original integer), is the current cell empty, and is there another column to the right that I can next evaluate?

Overall Picture...

I have a table with identifier columns (fname, lname) and then additional columns to hold data. Most cells are NULL. When not NULL, the cells contain an integer.

I would like to turn the information in the first table into the second table.

Refer to weblink to see the picture I am describing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iChCr.png

As can be inferred, beginning with each non-null cell, 1 replaces the contents of that cell and in all successive adjacent columns, up to the number of columns equal to the value of the original cell. So, column C for John Doe held a 3, and in the new (or updated?) table, the contents of three columns C, D, E were given the value 1.

Notice that for Steve Smith, there is an overlap! The directions require columns C and D to be set to 1, but also the instruction from column A is to replace the contents of A,B,C,D,E and F with 1. In this case, columns C and D get the sum, hence each cell equals 2. The subsequent non-overlapping cells E, F are equal to 1 (the last columns to update starting from A).

Current outline to approach:

-find the last non-empty column

-store the value from the cell from that column

-beginning with the cell of that column and continuing to the last
    column or until reaching the value of the stored value, insert 1 (INT)

-re-scan the table to find the first non-empty column, preceding the
    columns now filled with number 1

-store the value from the cell from that column

-beginning with that column, insert numeral 1: (1)for as many columns equal the number stored, or until the last column is reached, continue to the right inserting 1, (2)if the value of the stored number has not been reached but a non-empty column is reached, then add 1 to the existing value in that cell

Based on my searching, I am able to use a long and ordered case statement to get the name of the last non-null column, and a long coalesce to obtain the value in that corresponding cell, and put those results in a temp table. But that's it :/

Suggestions are appreciated and questions are welcomed!

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: How many columns do you want to have?